# Webpage with 4 digit code input ->Restful transfer, with iBeacon Support

Tags: html, rest, logging, ibeacon

we currently log in our workers in an Filemaker Go app. 
We have a locally run program, REPMAKER, an FM GO app, that shows a keyboard, when the user types in his 4 digit code, the app has all possible 4 digit codes stored, if valid, an "entry" record is created. When the iOS device is idle it sends all these records to your Human Resources DB. This runs OK for years. 
Now.. I would like to substitute this permitting that users on any device iOS or Android can access a webpage, see the keyboard, type in their codes, the webpage would send a restful query to the server, see if the code is valid, if valid create the record directly in our HR DB and give an "OK" message to the user. 
To avoid users to log in outside of the company, this webpage on the device, would check the devices Geolocation.. or better still, its aproximity with an iBeacon, which I acquired and will install.

Is that possible? Is there HTML code, that can access geolocation with Javascript?, with all the privacy concerns? Is there an iBeacon HTML way to get the proximity of an iBeacon to Permit data entry ?
Any ideas?

Comment: There is no way to access Bluetooth beacons in we apps.  You can access latitude and longitude with user permission.

Comment: So.. one would have to write an app, for iOS and Android. That could check the proximity of an iBeacon.. No way doing this in a webpage?

Comment: You cannot do it in a webpage as of January 2020.  See related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44633517/1461050  You must build a native Android or iOS app