# How to do indoor geolocalization with a web application?

Tags: javascript, web, progressive-web-apps, indoor-positioning-system

Is there a way to do indoor location in a phone Web app or a PWA?
Apparently, bluetooh scanning to detect beacon [is not yet available](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/scan.html)...

But another method seems to exist according to [this post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/localisation-indoor-et-pwa-progressive-webapps-ciprian-melian/). I translate it for non-French speakers:

> Livdeo SAS is carrying out a major innovation for indoor localization and proximity notifications in progressive web apps (PWA) distributed with its GEED solution in museums, cultural, heritage and tourist locations.
>
> Thanks to this technological innovation, no more need for beacons, bluetooth or GPS to be located! Visitors' devices are located automatically, after the user's authorisation, without the need to download an application from a store and without the need for an internet connection.
>
> *Example of localisation inside buildings with proximity notifications at the Galerie Lympia in Nice for the exhibition Giacometti - L'oeuvre Ultime.*

But, they didn't give any information about the method they use.

Precision: I know several SDK exist to do indoor location in *native* mobile apps. But isn't what I want to do. I would like to create a *Web* application to avoid app stores and mandatory installations.

Thanks you all for your help,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

BLE(Bluetooth low energe) beacon with Weighted least squares method can locate the position you are. Put beacons on wall or celling and mark theri location(x,y). They will brodacast rssi(Received Signal Strength Indicator). The RSSI receiced by your phone should be filtered first and then use Weighted least squares method to locate about three meters accuracy position.

Comment: Unfortunately, search beacon with only web technologies looks not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44633517

Answer (score 0):

if the store is in your hand you could locate the user/the phone and publish the position. E.g. by sending an ultra sound from the mobile phone or the store. Or what ever detection of the phone you have.

Comment: Interesting proposal. It's probably not simple to put in place, however.
Thanks,